# Change values in xml, Xamarin ios C#

Tags: c#, ios, xml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm want change values in xml, but it isn't changing

My code:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "myFile.xml");
        doc.Load (filePath);
        Console.WriteLine ("Zagruzilsa");
        Console.WriteLine (doc.OuterXml);

    send_zakaz.TouchUpInside += (o,s) => {

            using (var client = new WebClient ()) {

            street = ulitsa.Text;
            kvart = kvartira.Text;
            house = dom.Text;
            FIO = fio.Text;
            code = kod.Text;
            telephone = tel.Text;
            comment = coment.Text;

            var values = new NameValueCollection ();

            values ["Order"] = doc.OuterXml;
            values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{StreetName}", street.ToString()); 
            values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{FlatName}", kvart);
            values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{HouseName}", house);
            values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{FIO}", FIO);
            values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{Code}", code);
            values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{Phone}", telephone);
            values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("..", comment);
            Console.WriteLine("Proverka "+street);
            Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);


            values ["OrderText"] = "hello";
```

I have same xml like in start of activity.
What is wrong in my code?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update the doc.OuterXml? The Xml document seems to be a template that you are using so I would guess that it needs to remain with the original placeholders, such as {StreetName}, and then another xml document generated based on that template, or even just a string of xml.

The code as written is not modifying the XmlDocument doc. The code is copying the xml string into the values NameValueCollection and then updating that copy of the xml not the original XmlDocument.

I assume you can just use the string returned from values["Order"]. I would guess that it does not need to be loaded into an XmlDocument again, or even into the XmlDocument doc variable, if you are going to use it with the WebClient and call an API with it.

Comment: I write this code in Android project on Xamarin (C#) and it work's well

Comment: I try load doc.OuterXml, Replace some values and send this xml